# Самый быстрый способ объединить 2 массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

**Дано**

Два массива, каждый произвольной длинны.

```
const arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const arr2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

**Задача**

Нужно написать решение, которое самым оптимальным способом объединит два массива.

В первую очередь хочется получить решение с лучшим быстродействием, а при прочих равных - можно выбрать то, которое потребляет меньше памяти (ресурсов).

**Результаты моих экспериментов**

Сначала я написал решение через **arr1.concat(arr2)**, затем через **arr1.push(...arr2)**, а после решил сравнить их быстродействие.

Сравнение двух способов описанных выше меня не особо впечатлили, однако я продолжил изыскания и добавил еще несколько вариантов решения ([результаты экспериментов на jspref (UPD 1)](https://jsperf.app/mofiyi/2)). Когда я увидел результаты пятого решения - я удивился:

[image: Результат сравнения производительности решений]

Самый неочевидный для меня вариант решения - оказался самым быстрым.

Сходу я не придумал других вариантов, которые принципиально отличались бы от тех, которые я попробовал. А отсюда,

**Вопрос**

Можете ли вы предложить более быстрый (оптимальный) вариант решения? Уверен, я учел далеко не все...

**UPD**

Добавил в список проверок результаты решения предложенного @CrazyElf. Результат стал еще лучше!

[image: Обновленный список 1]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144918/discussion-on-question-by-kirill-----2-); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.